# how to add multiple command buttons inside of xamarin listview using MVVM?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin

I am trying to create a listview where users can select the list item to view the store and also be able to click on the image to take them to the product detail.
How can I add a command in the ViewCell?

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myData}" x:Name="myListView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStore}" > 
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate> 
        <ViewCell>  
        <Grid>    
              <Label Text="{Binding Title}" /> 
              <Image Source="product.png" >
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                         <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ItemTapCommand}" CommandParameter="Id" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image> 
           </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

```
    public ICommand ItemTapCommand => new Command(ShowSelectedProductAsync());

    private async Task ShowSelectedProductAsync()
    {
      //take them to view the item detail
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to bind to a command that is not located on the individual item within the ListView; the BindingContext on your `Image` is the individual items inside your `myData` collection.

With other frameworks, for example, Wpf, you would simply use the `RelativeSource` part of binding to tell the control to look for your command on the BindingContext of another control, however this isn't possible in Xamarin Forms (RelativeSource is not supported).

What you can do is the following, but it requires your UserControl to have an `x:Name`:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Bindind Path=BindingContext.ItemTapCommand,
                                        Source={x:Reference MyUserControl}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
```

What this says is to use the UserControl as the source for the binding, and the property is a nested property on that UserControl composed of BindingContext.ItemTapCommand.

As a bonus, I updated the code because I felt that you probably meant to bind the value of the Id property of each record as the command parameter, and not merely to send the string "Id" as the command parameter.

Comment: I am not clear on the UserControl.  This code is in xaml page, I am not using it as a usercontrol where it get embedded in the xaml page.  Is that what you mean?  If not What will be the MyUserControl?

Comment: @wil: Anything higher up in the xaml graph which has the correct `BindingContext`. I made an assumption it was a `UserControl` but it could just as easy be a `Page` or anything else higher up. Heck, you can even use the ListView since it already has a name (myListView).

Comment: that's what I figured.  Thanks much.  I will give this a try tonight.